# How to remove keyboard. Normal method not working. objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have this code.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    //If user presses next go to next textfield
    if (textField == self.emailTextField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [self.passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.passwordTextField) {
        [self.passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

This line below runs but all it does is make the textfield inactive and leaves the keyboard there. Then if you tap on the keys on keyboard then it does nothing.

```
[self.passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

This is not a duplicate question because the normal method is not working for some reason.

Comment: Is your `self.passwordTextField` `nil` ?

Comment: try thid [self.view endEditing:YES];

Comment: Just try `[textField resignFirstResponder];` instead of `[self.passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```